# ui:include not updateing on selection of row in dataTable

Tags: primefaces, uiinclude

On selecting a row, I need to update the page which is in ui:insert of p:dialog. What my issue is when the page is loaded I can select the row and fetch the data. After selection of another row, I am not able to fetch. There is no action going on.
This is my dataTable

```
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="samples" />
    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="samples" />


    <p:column headerText="SNo" style="width:20px;" >
        #{rowIndex+1}
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="PatientId">
        #{patServ.patientOrder.patientEpisode.patientRegistration.patientId}
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Patient Name" >
        #{patServ.patientOrder.patientEpisode.patientRegistration.firstName} #{patServ.patientOrder.patientEpisode.patientRegistration.lastName}
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Visit ID">
        #{patServ.patientOrder.patientEpisode.id}
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Order ID">
        #{patServ.patientOrder.id}
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Barcode ID" >
        <p:outputLabel value="#{resultEntryBean.getBarcodes(patServ.id)}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Department Name" >
        #{loginBean.getSpecialityName( patServ.serviceLabData.serviceHeaderData.speciality )}
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Service Name" >
        #{patServ.serviceLabData.serviceHeaderData.serviceName}
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Ordered Date">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{patServ.createdOn}">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a" type="date" timeZone="IST" />
        </p:outputLabel>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Status">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{resultEntryBean.status == 3 ? 'Acknowledged': resultEntryBean.status == 5 ? 'Result Entered': resultEntryBean.status == 6 ? 'Result Authorized' : 'Result Deauthorized'}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:commandButton value="Print" icon="ui-icon-print" update="reportContent" disabled="#{empty resultEntryBean.selectedPatientService}" onclick ="PF('templateDlg').show()" ajax="true"/>
    </p:column>


</p:dataTable>
```

and im updating xhtml in ui:include here in the dialog box

```
  <p:dialog id="mainDialog" header="Selected Template" widgetVar="templateDlg">
    <h:panelGroup id="reportContent">
        <ui:include src="#{resultEntryBean.selectedTemplate()}.xhtml"></ui:include>
</h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

How should I update the xhtml file in the ui:include of p:dialog